# C# calculate mean of the values in int array

Tags: c#, arrays, mean

What's the problem when I try to print the average of the values in int array and it prints out something totally different as many times as I have values.

```
int[] numbers;
numbers = new int[5];
Console.WriteLine("give five integer numbers:");
numbers[0] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
numbers[1] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
numbers[2] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
numbers[3] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
numbers[4] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int sum = 0;

foreach (int x in numbers) {
    sum += x;
    int aver = sum / numbers.Length;  
    Console.WriteLine("average: {0}",aver);
}
```

Comment: Use LINQ `numbers.Average()`

Comment: You must calculate average outside foreach

Comment: make `sum` be a *floating point* value: `double sum = 0.0`;

Comment: move the line 'int aver = sum...' out of the foreach loop

Comment: To fix your code, move the `int aver` line outside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Average should be outside the loop:

```
foreach (int x in numbers) 
{
   sum += x;
}

int aver = sum / numbers.Length;  
Console.WriteLine("average: {0}",aver);
```

**Or using Linq Extension Methods:**

```
Console.WriteLine("average: {0}", numbers.Average());
```

Answer (score 5):

You could rephrase the loops as

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (int x in numbers)
{
    sum += x;
}
int aver = sum / numbers.Length;
```

or simply do the calculation as

```
int aver = numbers.Average();
```

by using Linq.

Comment: I think it should be ```double aver = numbers.Average()``` regarding to ```Average()``` 's return type

Answer (score 3):

Or with linq : `var aver = numbers.Average();`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399409(v=vs.110).aspx

I ll complete my answer with what is the hood under `Average()` so ;)

```
  public static double Average(this IEnumerable<int> source) {
       if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
       long sum = 0;
       long count = 0;
       checked {
          foreach (int v in source) {
              sum += v;
              count++;
          }
       }
       if (count > 0) return (double)sum / count;
       throw Error.NoElements();
   }
```

Comment: "Don't think, use linq" - is this really an answer?. Under the hood Linq does the `foreach` _for_ you; there's nothing wrong with using Linq, but I hope the OP is also trying to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
foreach (int x in numbers) {
    sum += x;
    int aver = sum / numbers.Length;  Console.WriteLine("average: {0}",aver);
}
```

To

```
foreach (int x in numbers) {
    sum += x;
}
int aver = sum / numbers.Length;  Console.WriteLine("average: {0}",aver);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way and clean code for ***calculating average of array elements*** using below code:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
int sum = 0;
int average = 0;

Console.WriteLine("give five integer numbers:");

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    numbers[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Array.ForEach(numbers, x => sum += x);
average = sum / numbers.Length;
Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", average);
```

With `Array.ForEach` you can access to all of elements in Array and using any operand for it.