# Is there a faster way of calculating with a list?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a grade calculator. The List `NotenListe` is used to save all grades and calculate with them.
My problem is that I found nothing to make this code easier and more general. Now if the List is longer than 2 it wouldn't work.

I tried it with `for` but the application is shutting down then.

```
if (Daten.NotenListe.Count == 1)
{
    schnitt = Daten.NotenListe[0] + ".0";
    Schnitt.Text = schnitt;
} else if (Daten.NotenListe.Count == 2)
{
    schnitt = (Daten.NotenListe[0] + Daten.NotenListe[1]) / Daten.NotenListe.Count + "";
    Schnitt.Text = schnitt;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `NotenListe`? And to calculate the median (Durchschnitt) you need to sum all elements in the list and divide by the number of elements: `schnitt = ((float)Daten.NotenListe.Sum() / Daten.NotenList.Count).ToString();`

Comment: "but the application is shutting down then." how exactly should we imagine this scenario? Is there no error message? Are you using visual studio? any debugger at your disposal?

Comment: What is the code of the `for` loop you tried? Why does the program shut down? (Exit code)

Comment: The type of `NotenListe` is `List<double>`. But that code really helped me.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [Average](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Average_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Single__)

Comment: You should address the problem(s) you encountered with the `for` loop. It was probably something pretty basic that should be addressed. There are other methods, such as those mentioned by other commenters. Though it should be pretty clear from what you've tried that using `if`/`else` statements are not a realistic/maintainable way to work with `List`s.

Comment: have a look at this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966950/c-sharp-calculate-mean-of-the-values-in-int-array). If the answer there is what you were looking for we can close this post as a duplicate

Comment: if you have `double`s in your list you can get weird number representations in this line`schnitt = Daten.NotenListe[0] + ".0";` What if the value is `34.567` you would get `34.567.00`

Comment: `Schnitt.Text = $"{Daten.NotenListe.Average():f1}";` - take average and format the value returned with 1 digit after the decimal point

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that's easy enough for me... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling the method Average

```
NotenListe.Average();
```

also you can put a safeguard for an empty list

```
double average = NotenListe.Count > 0 ? NotenListe.Average() : 0.0;
```

Comment: @FireGuy: Even if you end up using this method, I'd try and implement it without using `Average()` just for exercise.

Comment: And how do I do it that is rounded in two places after the comma (double)?

Comment: Math.Round(average, 2)

Comment: That's a formatting issue. See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: My Code now is ```double schnitt;
schnitt = Daten.NotenListe.Sum() / Daten.NotenListe.Count;```
Shouldn't it be a double when I have for example 3 and 5 in the list?

Comment: @FireGuy how can this be your code? in your post `schnitt` is a string? : `schnitt = Daten.NotenListe[0] + ".0";`

Comment: I'm really sorry that I am so dumb :D just coding since one week

Comment: @FireGuy: If you concern about *formatting* (say, you want `1` digit after the decimal point), just provide the format string (`f1`) `Schnitt.Text = $"{Daten.NotenListe.Average():f1}";`